# protractor browser.sendKeys not updating ng-model in ie

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, testing, protractor

I am not sure if this is due to the general flakiness of IE, but I can see that IE will inconsistently fail to deal with data binding.

Specifically, I can see through debug attempts that sendKeys will only be in sync with ng-model up until the last character with sendKeys, then get out of sync.

I have attempted all sorts of hacks, even creating a sendKeys method in browser to try to go around it.

```
browser.sendKeys = function(elementLocator, value) {
elementLocator.sendKeys(value)
var triggerEvent = function(elem) {
  var inputEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
  inputEvent.initEvent("input", true, false);
  elem.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

  var changeEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
  changeEvent.initEvent("change", true, false);
  elem.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

  var ngChangeEvent = document.createEvent("Event");
  ngChangeEvent.initEvent("ng-change", true, false);
  elem.dispatchEvent(ngChangeEvent);

  var event = document.createEvent("Event");
  event.initEvent("hashchange", false, true);
  document.body.dispatchEvent(event);

  event = document.createEvent("Event");
  event.initEvent("popstate", false, true);
  document.body.dispatchEvent(event);

  angular.element(document.body).scope().$apply()
}
browser.executeScript(triggerEvent, elementLocator, value)
elementLocator.click()
```

}

None of it appears to work.

Comment: Please look at the Protractor issue on Internet Explorer on GitHub. This is a known issue and is documented there. Think about using the 32 bit version of the IEDriverServer or use Edge to test.

Comment: I am currently using SauceLabs to test internet explorer and am using IE driver version 2.53.1, which is the 32 bit version. Using Edge to test defeats the purpose of trying to validate that IE works for my specific scenario, and I think the issue with the 64 bit driver is slow sendKeys. I can see that keys are entered quickly enough with sendKeys, so I don't think that's the issue.